# Hiding boot screen for kiosk usage

Tags: pi-3, boot, gui, kiosk, tkinter

I'm developing a kiosk with raspberry pi. What I want to do is, when my customer power up the kiosk, it should start directly from the tkinter GUI that I designed. Even if I still have problems with auto start of tkinter python program, I also want to hide booting screen and 4 raspberries on the screen. Is it possible or anyone already did this?

Comment: Have you considered simply leaving the Pi always on? As most kiosks I've seen are plugged into the wall all the time, also maybe you should consider buying the Pi a battery for backup as it will give the illusion of the Pi booting instantly

Comment: Yes it will remain on but sometimes customer will want to move it to an other location. Anyway I've found the solution to my question. But still I cannot automatically run my tkinter program after boot. @MohammadAli

Comment: Have you tried this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: Try this answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59310/remove-boot-messages-all-text-in-jessie It works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution.

If you want to remove the 4 raspberry logos on startup:
- Open the file `/boot/cmdline.txt`.
- Add a space and `logo.nologo` to the end.

If anybody wants to remove the Pixel wallpaper at the startup, remove the "splash" word in the same file.

And also you can make `console=tty4` if you want to push the logs to the fourth virtual terminal and dont show them on startup.

And add a space in the end and add `loglevel=3`. This sets the severity of the logging level to “warning and above”.

Comment: Worth emphasizing that `cmdline.txt` *should all be one line*; as Enis says intially, use a space, not a newline, between different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on a website, if you sudo nano `/boot/cmdline.txt` and then change `console=tty1` to `console=tty3` add these at the end of the line: `loglevel=3 quiet logo.nologo`so `logo.nologo` hides the 4 raspberry pis (if you are running a 4 core processor or 1 on a 1 core)