# How to enable and see the bootup messages of the system console?

Tags: pi-3, boot, raspbian-stretch

Running latest Raspbian Stretch, and would like to see the typical powerup boot log console messages as shown in most other Linux distributions. However, it seem that these have been disabled and replaced by the 4 strawberries and a flash screen. I still want to automatically enter GUI after.

**How can I get these console messages while powering up?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59310/remove-boot-messages-all-text-in-jessie/73389#73389) answer.

Just edit the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file, and remove the `quiet` directive.

```bsh
# cat /boot/cmdline.txt
#dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=xxxxxxxx-yy rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

cp /boot/cmdline.txt ~/boot_cmdline_bak.txt
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Reboot and enjoy the reading!

Comment: You can also edit cmdline.txt using a Windows PC:

Plug in the microSD card. Windows will mount a drive called "boot". There you can find the file `cmdline.txt`. Edit it using an editor as simple as, e.g., notepad.