# (RetroPie) Can't use my splashscreen as a loading screen anymore

Tags: boot, retropie

I don't know if it's the recent updated, but I used to have my 30s splashcreen video as my loading screen

But, now I got a linux kernel version text between the Splashscreen and the Emulation Station loading screen

I did all the steps from both of these tutorials:
https://retropie.org.uk/docs/FAQ/#how-do-i-hide-the-boot-text

[Remove boot messages (all text) in Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59310/remove-boot-messages-all-text-in-jessie)

And by doing that, I got rid of all the texts, but I still got a 1s black screen between the Splashcreen and the Emulation Station Loading Screen, and I wanted to get rid of that, so I could use a longer Splashscreen video as the loading screen again

And, before asking what changes I did before this started happening, I only updated the new version of Retropie and enabled SSH

Thank you!